# datalist is not getting populated in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have following code written in AngularJS (simple HTML and its controller) and I mapped them in my state file

**main.html**

```
<input class="serialSearch" data-ng-placeholder="Serial #" data-ng-model ="serialNum" list="suggestion"/>
            <datalist id="suggestion">
                <option  data-ng-repeat="suggest in sugesstions.values"> {{suggest.title}}</option>
            </datalist>
```

**mainController**

```
$scope.sugesstions = {};    
var queryString= {"querystring" : ""+"q=name:"+$scope.serialNum+"*&qt=autocomplete-model&hl=true&hl.fl=name","$skip" : "0","$top" : "75"};
        searchResource.getList(queryString).then(
                function(data) {
                    $scope.sugesstions = data.items;
                }
        );
```

When I enter anything in my searchBox is calls the resource and returns me data, but in this case `searchResource.getList` is never getting called when there is anychange in searchBox content. WHY?

Comment: Did you try to debug? what you see under `function(data)`. please add to HTML: `<pre>{{sugesstions|json}}</pre>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing textbox content and are expecting that the querying mechanism is fired again you need to attach `ng-change` event directive

```
<input class="serialSearch" data-ng-placeholder="Serial #" data-ng-model ="serialNum" list="suggestion" ng-change='search()'/>
```

In controller

```
$scope.search=function() {
   var queryString= {"querystring" : ""+"q=name:"+$scope.serialNum+"*&qt=autocomplete-   model&hl=true&hl.fl=name","$skip" : "0","$top" : "75"};
        searchResource.getList(queryString).then(
                function(data) {
                    $scope.sugesstions = data.items;
                }
        );
}
```